# Nodejs and PHP (Client side)

Tags: php, node.js, client

I have created the server side for nodejs and from my web application (PHP), I can send data to the nodejs as it is output from the commandline. Now I need to implement the client side on my web application to listen to the server and output this data.

I have no idea how to do this the right way as I tried searching around for days and all I can find are articles on creating nodejs Server, no real world implementation example/tutorials. The nearest eexample I can find is http://goo.gl/zi2xqX where its using a setimeout function like so:

```
function load_tweets() {  
        $.getJSON("/stream", function(tweets) {  
            $.each(tweets, function() {  
                $("<li>").html(this.text).prependTo(tweet_list);  
            });  
            load_tweets();  
        });  
    }  

    setTimeout(load_tweets, 1000);
```

Is this the correct way to retrieve data from nodejs server?

Comment: 1. Should node.js actively push data to php, or should php pull data?
2. Why do you need php in between? You can go with express.js and javascript on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using socket.io use something like this:

**Server**

```
io.sockets.socket(clientId).volatile.emit("requestName", data);
```

**Client**

```
socket.on("requestName", function (data) {
    //do stuff with data
});
```

This is assuming you have clients connecting and you are recording there connection Ids. If you don't, I recommend looking up some socket.io tutorials as there are much better ones out there than I can write.